# jQuery Mobile CORS 405 error

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, jquery-mobile, nginx, same-origin-policy

I've read through SO and tried everything I could find online, but I'm still getting the following error when doing a jQM AJAX request for a different domain:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://a.b.c/search.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

jQM code is dead simple:

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() 
{
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});


$(document).on('vclick', '#btnConfirmOrder', function(event)
{
    $.ajax({url: baseUrl + 'order.php',
        data: {"shoppingCart" : shoppingCart, "userId":1},
        type: 'post',          
        async: 'true',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() 
        {   
            $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"a", text:"wait...", textonly:true, textVisible: true});
        },
        complete: function() {

            $.mobile.loading('hide');   
        },
        success: function (result) 
        {           
            showMsg("success.");            
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //#err
            console.log((jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            showMsg("error.");
        }
    });
});
```

This is the nginx conf (also tried the one at http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  a.b.c;
    root   /etc/nginx/html/ws2;


location / {

        index  index.html index.htm;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers   Content-Type;
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age         86400;

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

#cors
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you calling `mobileinit` after jquery.js and before jquery-mobile.js in head?

Comment: It was after both jquery.js and jquery-mobile.js. However, I changed it to be in between these two calls but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried it without JQM? if access-origin is set to `*` it should work.

Comment: I have tried it without JQM, I get the same error if I execute the request using Postman.

Comment: Then it's most likely a server-side issue.

Comment: Definitely a server-side issue, as I just tested the app using Apache and it works. I've tried two different conf for nginx and none seems to work, what's wrong with this?

Comment: I have edited the tags to make them more specific to your issue and to draw more attention. Feel free to change them to something more specific.